# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returns null in ActionResult Method

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization

I have the next Json document that I'm trying to deserialize:

```
{
  "General": {
    "Items": [
      {
        "fId": "divisionID",
        "frmt": "Text"
      },
      {
        "fId": "wcctOwnerID",
        "frmt": "Text"
      },
      {
        "fId": "qreID",
        "frmt": "Text"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have this classes:

```
public class Item
{        
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fId")]
    public string fId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "frmt")]
    public string frmt { get; set; }
}


public class General
{        
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize with this line:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + @"\Utils\OptionsByDB.json"))
{
    var json = r.ReadToEnd();
    Utils.General items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Utils.General>(json);                    
}
```

But it returns null. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you debug your code, the `json` variable has any value?

Comment: Yeah it has a string with my json doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your JSON isn't a `General` object.

Is a object that **has** a `General` object inside it:

You need a class declaration like this:

```
public class JsonObject{

     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "General")]
     public General rootObject {get; set;}
}
```

And then use:

```
var jsonConverted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(json);
```